# Different processors have different assembly language code then which syntax to be used to solve questions in competitive exams

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, processor, instruction-set

Mov dst,scr// in ARM PROCESSOR
Mov scr,dst // in intel processor     scr=source
Dst= destination

Comment: (*scr=source* - normally it's abbreviated to *src*, not *scr*). *which syntax to be used to solve questions in competitive exams* - typically, the one that you've studied during the course. If you've studied both x86 and ARM, the exam task should state which one to use for this particular task.

Comment: Which competitive exam are you talking about?  It obviously depends on which ISA the exam setter picks.  (Although I'd guess that they might invent a simple toy instruction set and include an instruction list and register set as part of the exam, so everyone's on equal footing if it's an actual exam, not a contest or something).

Comment: Also, Intel-syntax assembly language uses `op dst, src`, same as ARM (although it's usually 2-operand not 3-operand like ARM).  Maybe you're thinking of AT&T syntax for the same CPUs, like `movl $1, %edx`

Comment: Okay now I have understood the concepts

Comment: for the same reason that one cannot assume which assembly language is used, one cannot assume what a competition would use (note that intel vs at&t is minimal with respect to the x86 differences between assemblers, and there are more non-x86 processors for every x86 processor you buy, and it is not a good isa to learn, so why would anyone have a competition using x86?).

Comment: if this is just an exam thing and not a competition thing then a school worth going to would understand programming languages and would solve this problem for you (with proper documentation, and/or indication of the tools being used and it is on you to learn the language).  Unfortunately this is obviously not the case (that universities are this good).  Usually though at school you are in a sandbox where your part of the task is a tiny part of the big picture so in that context you are loaded up with training wheels, a life vest,a  helmet, wrist guards, etc to keep you safe...

Answer (score -1):

It's all about ISA(Instruction sets architecture), don't look at Syntax of different Architecture Assembly language.

For GATE(Graduate aptitude test in engineering) point of view learn any of these ISA

MCS-51, 8085, x86